# spring boot - how to avoid "Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface" in HTTP controller handler?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot REST API application, I need to handle HTTP POST by accepting a strongly-typed list as my input:

```
@RestController
public class CusttableController {

    static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CusttableController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/custtable/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public String updateCusttableRecords(List<Custtable> customers) {
        try {
                for (Custtable cust : customers) {

                Custtable customer = (Custtable) custtableDao.getById(Custtable.class, 
                        new CusttableCompositeKey 
                        (cust.getAccountnum(),cust.getPartition(),cust.getDataareaid()));
```

In the Jersey version of this API, this worked just fine, but with Spring Boot, it gives me this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface
```

What is the proper way for me to accept a strongly-typed List in Spring Boot?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try to add [RequestBody](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) annotation to your method definition

```
@RequestMapping(value="/custtable/update", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String updateCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {
    //Method body 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had made a typo accidentally wrapping a class in a list.
Removing the typo allowed serialization to happen correctly via spring data rest + jackson.

```
List<MyClass> a; // typo
MyClass = a;// fix
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, that was my problem, only slightly different.  I had the wrong name for the entity being returned...