# Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface in GET request

Tags: java, spring, list, rest, spring-boot

In my spring boot REST API application, I need to handle HTTP `GET` by accepting a strongly-typed list as my input:

```
@RestController
public class CusttableController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/custtable", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(List<Custtable> customers) {...}
```

This gives me this error:

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface

What is the proper way for me to accept a strongly-typed List in Spring Boot, in a `GET` request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring boot - how to avoid "Failed to instantiate \[java.util.List\]: Specified class is an interface" in HTTP controller handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427311/spring-boot-how-to-avoid-failed-to-instantiate-java-util-list-specified-cl)

Comment: No it's not cause this time I am handling a GET request, and the solution does not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not send a request body with a `GET` request. If you have to send it, Change the request method to `POST`

```
@RestController
public class CusttableController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/custtable", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {...}
}
```

Comment: Isn't possible to send a `GET` request with an object?

Comment: @Anna No, It will ignore the body sent using `GET` request

Answer (score 9):

Add the annotation [`@RequestBody`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html) which says that the parameter is bound to the body of the HTTP request.

Another thing is that HTTP method `GET` method does not include a request body, so `@RequestBody` would be ignored. Change the method to `POST`.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/custtable", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {
    // ...
}
```

Since Spring 4.3, you can use [`@PostMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PostMapping.html):

```
@PostMapping(value="/custtable")
public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {
    // ...
}
```

Although according to the REST principles, the method POST should be used to create a new resource:

> Request that the resource at the URI do something with the provided entity. Often POST is used to create a new entity, but it can also be used to update an entity.

However, this is the only workaround since your request is a bit unusual. I recommend you to change List to anything else and simpler to be passed through [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) as part of URL. For example, you might need only IDs of those objects. Then you can use `GET`:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/cuttable", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestParam List<String> id) {
    // ...
}
```

URL would look like:

```
localhost:8080/cuttable?id=1&id=2&id=3
```

Comment: Should I change it to a `POST` even if all what I do is to get information from the database based on the sent list?

Comment: `POST` doesn't care what do you send to the database. Although according to the REST principles, the method `POST` should be used to create a new resource. However, this is the only workaround since your request is a but unusual. I recommend ou to change `List<Custtable>` to anything else and simpler to be passed through `@RequestParam` as part of URL - ex. Do you need all the list or just ID of those of objects?

Comment: I need all the list. Thanks for the details!

Comment: You are welcome. I see you stick with the first solution I described - use the `POST` method.

Comment: 1. Of course POST is used not only to create a new resource, for example it can be used to change some resource state as well (i.e. reset password)

2. I'm surprised that even when I have "@RestController" I needed to use "@RequestBody", otherwise I had this exeption as in question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add @RequestBody to the customer parameter and use POST instead of GET.

```
@RestController
public class CusttableController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/custtable", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {...}
```

If you still want to use GET method then you could do the following:

```
@RestController
public class CusttableController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/custtable", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestParam(name = "chooseAnAlias") List<Custtable> customers) {...}
```

and then make the call in the following manner:

*domain.com/custtable?chooseAnAlias=value1&chooseAnAlias=value2&..chooseAnAlias=valueN*

Comment: I have this error using `@RequestBody`: `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing`. I think it's because I am in a GET request.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use @RequestBody and contentType: "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public List<MyObject> getCusttableRecords(@RequestBody List<Custtable> customers) {...}
```

You need to use `@RequestBody`

Comment: Seems like `@RequestBody` doesn't work well with GET requests :/

Comment: how r u triggering thr request? are you using swagger?

Comment: Yes with swagger

Comment: you should specify everything in the question. :) This is a known issue in swagger. This is a bug in swagger, Nothing wring with the code. try using Postman or some other tool to  send request or simply use curl

Comment: Indeed Swagger doesn't send the body for a GET request : https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2136

Comment: Ok thanks. If it's a swagger problem I will close this post. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Anna but according to HTTP standards, you should not send body with a GET request.

Comment: You're totally right. it's just that in this case, I really need a list of objects as an input. From what I saw, the best solution is to use a POST request. Thanks.